# My objects values won't save. Displays null

Tags: java, object, inheritance, arraylist, null

I have 3 classes:

1. Sportswear (superclass)
2. Jersey (subclass)
3. Driver

I have an ArrayList in my driver to hold all my jerseys created.
When the user inputs all the values (stock, price, product, team, kit, size, gender),
and it displays them back it shows null :

```
Product: null
In stock: 0
Price: 0
Team: 
Kit: 
Size: 
Gender:
```

The superclass (Sportswear) has the variables `stock, price and product` (so I can include other products, not just jerseys)

And the subclass (Jersey) contains the variables `team, kit, size, gender`. It also contains the method `jerseyDisplay()` which shows what is above.

In the driver after the values are inputted I put:

```
Jersey jersey = new Sportswear(stock, price, product, team, kit, size, gender);

sportswear.add(jersey);


jersey.jerseyDisplay();
```

Is this completely wrong? Why arn't the inputted values showing up?

The `jerseyDisplay()` method in the subclass `Jersey` is:

```
public void jerseyDisplay()
    {
        super.sportswearDisplay();

        System.out.println("Team: "+team);

        System.out.println("Kit: "+kit);

        System.out.println("Size: "+size);

        System.out.println("Gender: "+gender);
    }
```

@DessertIvy This is the Sportswear superclass:

```
public class Sportswear
{
    //instance variables
    private int stock;
    private float price;
    private String product;

    //blank constructor
    public Sportswear()
    {
        this.stock = 0;
        this.price = 0;
        this.product = "";
    }

    //detailed constructor
    public Sportswear(int s, float p, String pd)
    {
        this.stock = stock;
        this.price = price;
        this.product = product;
    }

    //setters
    public void setStock(int stock)
    {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product)
    {
        this.product = product;
    }

    //getters
    public int getStock()
    {
        return stock;
    }

    public float getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public String getProduct()
    {
        return product;
    }

    //increase stock
    public int increaseStock()
    {
        stock = stock++;
        return stock;
    }

    //decrease stock
    public int decreaseStock()
    {
        stock = stock - 1;
        return stock;
    }

    public void sportswearDisplay()
    {
        System.out.println("Product: "+product);
        System.out.println("In stock: "+stock);
        System.out.println("Price: "+stock);
    }

}
```

The constructor in the Jersey subclass:

```
public Jersey(int stock, float price, String product, String team, String kit, String size, String gender)
    {
        super(stock, price, product);
        this.team = "";
        this.kit = "";
        this.size = "";
        this.gender = "";
    }
```

Comment: why did you generate `(stock, price, product, team, kit, size, gender)` values, also please post the `jerseyDisplay()` method

Comment: It would help to show the code that actually does the display (jerseyDisplay method).

Comment: Please post the code you use to create `sportsware` and the code that loops through your array. Otherwise it is nearly impossible to tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: @Salah I need to save values to stock, price, product, team, kit, size, gender for a sportswear shop stock software for managing stock and recording purchases (as a project, not for an actually shop haha)

The jerseyDisplay() method in the subclass Jersey is:

public void jerseyDisplay()
    {
        super.sportswearDisplay();

        System.out.println("Team: "+team);

        System.out.println("Kit: "+kit);

        System.out.println("Size: "+size);

        System.out.println("Gender: "+gender);
    }

Comment: @DesertIvy I edited the Sportwear superclass in

Comment: the sportsweardisplay() has an error: price = stock

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau 

The `jerseyDisplay()` method in the subclass Jersey is:

`public void jerseyDisplay()
    {
        super.sportswearDisplay();

        System.out.println("Team: "+team);

        System.out.println("Kit: "+kit);

        System.out.println("Size: "+size);

        System.out.println("Gender: "+gender);
    }`

Comment: How does the Jersey() consctructor look like

Comment: @SaraSeppola I put it in

Comment: ok thx, are you sure that the values you send to the consctructor are defined?

Answer (score 1):

The problem are within your 2 contructors :

```
    //detailed constructor
public Sportswear(int s, float p, String pd)
{
    this.stock = stock;
    this.price = price;
    this.product = product;
}
```

and

```
public Jersey(int stock, float price, String product, String team, String kit, String size, String gender)
{
    super(stock, price, product);
    this.team = "";
    this.kit = "";
    this.size = "";
    this.gender = "";
}
```

You should initialize your variables with the values passed as parameters... or use your `setXXX` methods. In the constructor, it should look like this :

```
        //detailed constructor
public Sportswear(int s, float p, String pd)
{
    this.stock = s;
    this.price = p;
    this.product = pd;
}
```

Also, as mentionned earlier, this line 
`Jersey jersey = new Sportswear(stock, price, product, team, kit, size, gender);` shouldn't even compile... you probably meant `Jersey jersey = new Jersey(stock, price, product, team, kit, size, gender);`

Comment: Awh Yeah! Thanks a million! My products due in less than 8 hours so you're a saviour. Thanks man.